# chart js -data on chart in rotated form

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want the data on chart js line chart should be in a rotated form here is my code:

```
meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
      var data = iData[index].data;
      if(index <=  4 ){
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 4);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillText("" + data + ",", bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
        ctx.restore();
       }
   });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AzQn.png)
I want the data on a chart to be in a rotated form like the labels. I have tried the canvas rotate method but that does not give me the proper result, it is not positioned on `bar._model.x` and `bar._model.y` positions.here is the image of it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t1Mn.png)
Can anyone suggest me the solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After rotating, the axes of the canvas are at an angle. If you try to use `fillText` with some `x` and `y`, they will be along the rotated axes, which is why the text is not in the correct position. Try instead to first `translate` to the correct position, then `rotate`, then `fillText` with `x = y = 0`.
This will place the text in the correct position, and then rotate it on the spot.

Also, you should call `save` before transforming the context's matrix.

Try the following:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 4);
ctx.fillText("" + data + ",", 0, 0);
ctx.restore();
```